# Desktop computer rebooting after ~3 hours

Tags: troubleshooting, hardware-failure

My desktop computer, less than a year old, has started rebooting automatically (as if power was suddenly lost and immediately restored), after ~3 hours of running.

After the first reboot in ~3 hours, it reboots repeatedly every 5-10 minutes at random.

If kept shut-down for a while, it then works for ~3 hours again before starting to reboot.

I thought this was a CPU overheating issue, but I monitored temperature, and it is 140F at worst (when CPU is highly taxed), and usually much cooler than that.

This is a Intel Haswell Core i5 processor with 4 GB Corsair RAM and a Corsair SSD and power supply, and **no** discrete GPU.

What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess either overheating or a faulty capacitor somewhere.  A virus infestation or a BIOS problem would not manifest that pattern.

Comment: You didn't give use the OS, but have you checked log or the windows event viewer?

Comment: @Tyson: No I haven't, and that's an excellent idea - thanks! (The OS is Windows 8.1.)

Comment: What is the OS, version and vendor information?

Comment: @mdpc: OS is Windows 8.1. No vendor. I purchased components and put them together myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are 5 (or even more) possible reasons that might cause this issue.

1. **CPU Overheat.** After some temperature our computer tries to keep the temperature down by restarting or shuting down your computer. Since you said that CPU operating at max at 60C, you should check your BIOS Settings for missconfigured values on Temperature Alerts.
2. **Virus** There are some viruses that causes your System to Restart after some specific actions. You can try cleaning your Computer with CCleaner, or some other Cleaning and AntiMalware software to ensure that your problem IS NOT any virus.
3. **Power deficiency**. This occurs when there isn't enough power to keep electricity flowing in your motherboard, or the power supply becomes faulty.
4. **Faulty Motherboard**. Malfunctioning capacitors on a Motherboard can create a wide range of issues. It is even possible for capacitors to fail due to a bad Power Source. A leaking capacitor is a very easy visual check. Open your case and take a look at the Motherboard. If you see a leaking capacitor (Google it), then replacement of the Motherboard is necessary. Be sure to check if your system is still under warranty before spending your money.
5. **BIOS**. Finally, the last and often trickiest to troubleshoot source of reboot problems: your computer's BIOS. If there is a problem in your BIOS, or sometimes even in the firmware for one of the other pieces of hardware installed in your machine, it could cause an instability and lead to one of those automatic restarts. Especially if the problem is in the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) portion. The good news is that these problems are much less common than they used to be in the bad old days. But it never hurts to check with your computer manufacturer to see if there's an updated BIOS available.

Ref: Previous Experience and [Dis](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-10149_102-292644/help-my-pc-keeps-rebooting-every-10-to-20-minutes/)